# Chrome Developer Tools for android crashing

Tags: android, debugging, google-chrome

I installed developer tools after this instructions: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview. When i go to my `http://localhost:9222` I see the pages I want to inspect but when I click on a page I get a blank page and Chrome on my tablet closes. I have USB debugging turned ON in my device and ADB server is working fine and recognizing my device. What have I missed?